# can't display ordered list of markdown

Tags: html-lists, markdown, hexo

I'am using Hexo to post my blog. I edited my blog by markdown. And I encountered with some problems when I try to use the ordered list and it can't be displayed normally.

Here is my code:

```
1. first
2. second
 + inner first
 + inner second
```

However, only disordered list was shown.
I would like it was shown as follow:
http://7xjj3m.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/20150622_0.jpg

but it was follow indeed:
http://7xjj3m.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/20150622_1.jpg

So, what's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by disordered list, can you please add it the question

Comment: I am sorry for I didn't specify my question clearly. I have made supplement to the question.

Comment: @郭天佑, please try using four spaces instead of one to indent the inner list.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have succeeded to indent the inner list. But the order number 1 and 2 weren't shown properly: http://7xjj3m.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/20150622_2.jpg

Comment: @郭天佑, is there anything else in the Markdown file?

Comment: No, there is nothing else. I am using hexo 3.0.1, hexo-renderer-marked and hexo-renderer-pandoc.

Comment: @郭天佑, do you get proper numbering if you remove the inner items, i.e. only include `1. first` and `2. second`?

Comment: @Chris, No, it didn't. It was shown as disordered list, even if I remove the inner items.

Comment: @郭天佑, I'm running out of suggestions. Do you have a stylesheet (CSS) that is showing numbered lists as something else? Look for [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type).

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is correct but you need to indent by four spaces. I would refrain from using tab because your computer / program could be defaulted to 2 instead of 4.

I use a markdown editor called Mou; and I inputed your syntax and got the proper result.